# Dependency between data store

Tags: rest, design-patterns, client-server, datastore

## TL;DR

What's the best way to handle dependency between types of data that is loaded asynchronously from different backend endpoints?

## Problem

My app fetches data from a backend, for each entity I have an endpoint to fetch all instances.
For example `api.myserver.com/v1/users` for `User` model and `api.myserver.com/v1/things` for `Thing` model.

This data is parsed and placed into data store objects (e.g. `UserDataStore` and `ThingDataStore`) that serve these models to the rest of the app.

#### Question

What should I do if the data that comes from `/things` depends on data that comes from `/users` and the fetch operations are async. In my case `/things` returns the `id` of a user that created them. This means that if `/things` returns before `/users`, then I won't have enough data to create the `Thing` model.

## Options

1. Have `/things` return also relevant `/users` data nested.

   This is bad because:

   - I'll then have multiple model instances `User` for the same actual user - one that came from `/users` and one that came nested in `/things`.
   - Increases the total payload size transferred.
   - In a system with some permission policy, data that is returned for `/users` can be different to `/things`, and then it'll allow partially populated models to be in the app.
2. Create an operational dependency between the two data stores, so that `ThingsDataStore` will have to wait for `UserDataStore` to be populated before it attempts to load its own data.

   This is also bad because:

   - Design-wise this dependency is not welcome.
   - Operational-wise, it will very quickly become complicated once you throw in another data stores (e.g. dependency cycles, etc).

What is the best solution for my problem and in general?
This is obviously not platform / language dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

1. Late initialization of `UserDataStore` in `ThingDataStore`. You will have to allow for creation an object that is not fully valid. And you will also need to add method that will give you an information whether `UserDataStore` is initialized or not. Not perfect, because for some time there will exists an invalid instance.
2. Create some kind of proxy or maybe a buider object for `ThingDataStore` that will hold all information about particular thing and will create `ThingDataStore` object as soon as `UserDataStore` related with this instance will be received.

Maybe it will help you. Good luck!